# how to insert values in a textbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I don't know how to add a value in a textbox.
This is the code:

```
       private void starecivilaComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This selection is not valid!");
        }
        else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            int score = 4;
        }
        else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            int score = 1;
        }
        else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            int score = 3;
        }
        else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 4)
        {
            int score = 2;
        }

    }
```

I want to insert the value of score in a textbox, so it will show me the score of each item i've selected from combobox.
I tried with this:

```
        private void scoringTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        scoringTextBox.Text = score.toString();
    }
```

But it doesn't recognize it. The error is: The name 'score' does not exist in this context. How can I make this work ?

Thank you.

Comment: By not defining it in that method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must declare variable **score** outside of ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged handler. You're declaring it in the handler and it's being used only in the method, not in the whole class (not in the whole form in your case).

```
public class Form1
{
    int score = 0;
    //somewhere in the code
    score = 1; //there is no need to specify 'int' here - you will create an local variable with the same name then
}
```

I recommend you to [learn through tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), because the question is rather simple.

Comment: Good answer. It not only answers the question asked, it answers the questions that should have been asked.

Comment: thank you , that's quite simple, i didn't observe that, 'cause i'm in a hurry to be ready for tonight. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

Though @psNytrancez answer is the simplest for you, you will not get far in C# without understanding how variables work.

The problem is with the lines that look like this:

```
else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    int score = 4;
}
```

it means that you create a variable "score", but that the variable will only exists between the two braces "{" and "}". In order to actually keep a value, you need to expand its [scope](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NemPMKTxM7w) (instruction video). if you edit all those lines to just read

```
else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    score = 4;
}
```

and instead put it outside the method declaration like this

```
int score =0;

private void starecivilaComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //the rest of the method.
```

then you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are declaring your score inside of the starecivilaComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged method so it is local to that method and cannot be accessed outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above, you must declare score outside of your private method but inside your class. Code should look similar to this:

```
private int score = 0;

private void starecivilaComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This selection is not valid!");
    }
    else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        score = 4;
    }
    else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        score = 1;
    }
    else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {
        score = 3;
    }
    else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 4)
    {
        score = 2;
    }

}

private void scoringTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    scoringTextBox.Text = score.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void starecivilaComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This selection is not valid!");
    }
    else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        scoringTextBox.Text = "4";
    }
    else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        scoringTextBox.Text = "1";
    }
    else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {
        scoringTextBox.Text = "3";
    }
    else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 4)
    {
        scoringTextBox.Text = "2";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it after this

```
else if (starecivilaComboBox.SelectedIndex == 4)
    {
        int score = 2;
    }
```

Add this

```
scoringTextBox.Text = score.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope for variable / object score is the problem
you are trying to access a variable that has limited scope (function level only)

simply create a private variable score so it can be accessed through the class.